# convert javascript event this with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am converting my previous JavaScript code to typescript.
Now i am running into the following issue. When i convert the old prototype code to classes and methods inside typescript, i have an issue with events:
Consider following code:

```
// call this class, provide the parameter of the column
var self = this;
cell.onclick = function () {
    self.makeTableSort(this); <== problem with parameter this.
};
```

The problem i have is that i need the object of the html element that is clicked.
where as "this" as parameter is not refering to the class object but to the html element.

EDIT: 
I have already something tried like below:

```
// call this class, provide the parameter of the column
cell.onclick = (event) => {
    this.makeTableSort(); <== missing parameter,
};
```

How do i convert this to TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cell.onclick = (event) => {
  this.makeTableSort(event.currentTarget);
};
```

Comment: Owke, somehow this works, but dont understand why, if i do console.log(event); i can see inside chromeDev that currentTarget is NULL??EDIT: but when i do console.log(event.currentTarget); then it does show the html cell s:

Comment: It's because event.currentTarget is changed after printing console.log and you're seeing changed object

Comment: Other way you can just pass `cell` variable `this.makeTableSort(cell);`

Comment: OMG!!! You are right!! you know i am already looking for this the past 5 hour!! Thanx for the quick help!!